# how to change stack content with call and ret?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

this code like simulation of Turing machine. i am detecting this code and i made a table about every single step of changing it's ok but i don't understand how to change stack content with **CALL AND RET**

```
.model small
.data
bant db 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

.code
.startup

mov si,4
call stateA
.exit

stateA proc near
cmp bant[si],0
je AB
jmp AC

AB:
mov bant[si],1
inc si
call stateB
jmp RTA

AC:
mov bant[si],1
dec si
call stateC

RTA: ret
stateA endp

stateB proc near
cmp bant[si],0
je BA
jmp BB

BA:
mov bant[si],1
dec si
call stateA
jmp RTB

BB:
mov bant[si],1
inc si
call stateB

RTB: ret
stateB endp
stateC proc near
cmp bant[si],0
je CB
jmp CHLT

CB:
mov bant[si],1
dec si
call stateB
jmp RTC

CHLT:
mov bant[si],1
inc si

RTC: ret
stateC endp

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RET doesn't write to the stack, but it does modify SP.  [CALL](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) writes a return address to the stack, as well as modifying SP.

The only value you can write to the stack is the IP of the instruction after the CALL, so I don't think it's possible to do very much with *just* CALL and RET instructions.

You're probably going to need to do it the normal way with MOV instructions and other instructions.  Usually with addressing modes relative to `[BP]`, after making a stack frame.

Answer (score 1):

There's neat trick how to load offset of some value on top of stack:

```
    call print_message   ; address of string is pushed on top of stack
    db "some text message to print",0  ; defined inside code
print_message:
    call some_print_function ; which want single argument on stack as "ptr to string"
    ; restore stack as needed (but don't do "ret", it would execute string)
```

But this is very likely of more usage in 32b mode, as the pushed offset is inside code segment `cs`, so in 16b real mode this would work well (conveniently) only with code which has everything in single segment and `cs = ds`. For example most of the ".com" executables would fit this description.

If your code is using more segments, then that print routine has to be written in a way to address that string through `cs:`, which is not very common.